# How to prevent AdView from causing the soft keyboard to push all my Views up?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, adview

The AdView and the 'background' view that occupies 90% of the space on the screen are both added to a RelativeLayout that is the activity root view. Everything works perfectly without the AdView, and with it, spawning the soft keyboard resizes the 'background' view and messes everything up.

I've tried doing `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in conjunction with four of the most popular hacks for checking if the soft keyboard is showing, and setting the AdView's visibility to `Gone` if it is. Doesn't work.

Is there something I can do with the activity root view and/or the way I'm adding the AdView and the 'background' view?

EDIT: I found a solution! In case someone with a similar question finds this, here's how I solved it.

I added a boolean variable 'boardShowing' to a Singleton. Actions that spawn the keyboard, such as the onClick of an EditText, turn off the AdView and set 'boardShowing' to true, and actions that despawn the keyboard set 'boardShowing' to false and start a 500 MS timer. If, after 500 MS, 'boardShowing' is still false, the AdView is turned back on.

Obviously this isn't thread safe, but if you're using threads you can do this sort of thing pretty easily with locks. Hope I helped!

Comment: please share XML file and screenshot

Comment: are you this attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`?

Comment: I've been using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"